# What are some of the advantages and disadvantages of user mode and kernel mode

Tags: operating-system

In an Operating System, threads are typically handled in user mode or kernel mode. What are some of the advantages and disadvantages of each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User-mode threads are scheduled in user mode by something in the process, and the process itself is the only thing handled by the kernel scheduler.

That means your process gets a certain amount of grunt from the CPU and you have to share it amongst all your user mode threads.

Simple case, you have two processes, one with a single thread and one with a hundred threads.

With a simplistic kernel scheduling policy, the thread in the single-thread process gets 50% of the CPU and each thread in the hundred-thread process gets 0.5% each.

With kernel mode threads, the kernel itself manages your threads and schedules them independently. Using the same simplistic scheduler, each thread would get just a touch under 1% of the CPU grunt (101 threads to share the 100% of CPU).

Answer (score 0):

> In an Operating System, threads are typically handled in user mode or kernel mode.

Typically threads are handled in kernel mode.

> What are some of the advantages and disadvantages of each?

In theory, the advantage of handling threads in user mode is that it avoids the cost of switching to/from kernel when a thread needs to wait for something (which can be relatively expensive as it involves privilege level switches). In practice this "advantage" often doesn't happen because the thread has to switch to kernel anyway, to ask kernel to do whatever the thread would wait for (e.g. switching to kernel to ask it to read data from a file and then returning to user-space to block/wait instead of blocking/waiting in the kernel while you're already in the kernel). Mostly; it only helps if the kernel isn't involved at all, which only really happens when user-space threads communicate with or share locks with other threads in the same process.

The advantage of handling threads in kernel is that the kernel can support thread priorities properly. For example, if you have two processes that both have a very high priority thread and a very low priority thread; then kernel can make sure CPU time is given to the high priority thread/s when possible (including pre-empting low priority threads when a high priority thread unblocks) because it knows about all threads; but user-space can't do this - one process doesn't know about threads belonging to a different process, so user threading will get it wrong and ruin performance (one process giving CPU time to its own very low priority thread while a very high priority thread belonging to a different process needs the CPU and doesn't get it).

The other advantage of handling threads in the kernel is that (especially for systems with multiple CPUs) the kernel has access to better information and can make smarter scheduling decisions. This includes balancing the load (from any number of processes) across all CPUs while taking into account "CPU topology" (NUMA, SMT, etc; possibly including heterogeneous CPUs - e.g. "big.LITTLE" arrangements); and making trade-offs between thread priorities, CPU temperatures and power consumption (e.g. if one of the CPU's is getting too hot, reduce that CPU's clock speed to let it cool down and use it for low priority threads so that the performance of high priority threads isn't effected).